# Integration problem regarding a continuous, non-negative function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration

"Assume that $g$ is continuous and non-negative on the interval $[a,b]$, as well as $\int_a^bg(x)dx=0$. Show that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$."

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\Delta x_i$ some arbitrary sub-interval $(i=1,2,...,n)$. The function $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $g$ is continuous on $\Delta x_i$. Thus $g$ certainly takes maximum and minium values $g_M$ and $g_m$ on this sub-interval.

Let $M_i=g_M$ and $m_i=g_m$ be the supremum and infimum of $g$ on $\Delta x_i$. There is a point $\alpha \in \Delta x_i$ such that $$g_M\geq g(\alpha)\geq g_m$$ $$M_i\geq g(\alpha)\geq m_i$$ $$\Delta x_i M_i \geq g(\alpha) \geq \Delta x_i m_i$$

and thus $$U(P,g)\geq \Delta x_i g(\alpha) \geq L(P,g).$$

As we take finer partitions of $[a,b]$, $n\to \infty$ and the upper and lower sums tend to $0$, since $\int_a^bg(x)dx=0$. Now $\Delta x_i>0\implies g(\alpha)=0.$ Since this sub-interval was arbitrary ( and might as well be $[a,b]$ ) we can conclude that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

I'm a bit unsure about the strength of my argument for the conclusion $g(x)=0$. Also, is it appropriate to treat the upper and lower sums as "limits", which both tend to a common value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that $$ \Delta x_i m_i \leq g(\alpha) \Rightarrow L(P,g) \leq \Delta x_i g(\alpha), $$ since $L(P,g)$ could possibly have a bunch of positive terms. Here's an outline for a proof I learned when I was stuck at office hours -

Let $\varepsilon > 0 $ be given. Suppose false! That is there exists $y \in [a,b]$ such that $g(y) \neq 0$. Then either $g(y) < 0$ or $g(y) > 0$. Without loss of generality, suppose $g(y) > 0$. By continuity of $g$ we know that it is positive on a neighborhood of y. Say on $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$. Then certainly $g$ is positive on $E := [y - \frac{\delta}{2}, y + \frac{\delta}{2}]$.

By monotonicity of the riemann integral, $$ \int_E g(x) dx \leq \int_a^b g(x) dx = 0.$$
Yet $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in E$ therefore $$ \int_E g(x) dx > 0. $$

Contradiction.

Comment: Whoops I meant to say positive on a neighborhood of y instead of f.